# Combine same flow structures in one function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have used below flow structure nearly more than 5 times. as most of the parts are identical. There is a separate use_case for each job. and each useCases return `Flow<Resource<MyType>>`. How can I combine idential parts in common function which job1, job2... functions use?

#### Job1

```
    private var job1Job: Job? = null
    private fun job1(param: Param) {
        job1Job?.cancel()
        job1Job = useCases1(param)
            .onEach { resource->
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = resource,
                        )
                    }
            }
            .catch {throwable->
                var currentTryCount = 
                var maxTryCount = 
                if ( throwable is BleReTryableError && currentTryCount < maxTryCount ) {
                    currentTryCount++
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Loading("loading message"),
                            currentTryCount = currentTryCount
                        )
                    }
                    throw BleReTryableError(throwable.message ?: "")
                } else {
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Error("error message"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .retry {
                delay(2500)
                it is BleReTryableError
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

#### Job2

```
    private var job2Job: Job? = null
    private fun job2(param: Param) {
        job2Job?.cancel()
        job2Job= useCases2(param)
            .onEach { resource->
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = resource,
                        )
                    }
            }
            .catch {throwable->
                var currentTryCount = 
                var maxTryCount = 
                if ( throwable is BleReTryableError && currentTryCount < maxTryCount ) {
                    currentTryCount++
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Loading("loading message"),
                            currentTryCount = currentTryCount
                        )
                    }
                    throw BleReTryableError(throwable.message ?: "")
                } else {
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Error("error message"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .retry {
                delay(2500)
                it is BleReTryableError
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

#### Job3

```
    private var job3Job: Job? = null
    private fun job3(param: Param) {
        job3Job?.cancel()
        job3Job= useCases3(param)
            .onEach { resource->
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = resource,
                        )
                    }
            }
            .catch {throwable->
                var currentTryCount = 
                var maxTryCount = 
                if ( throwable is BleReTryableError && currentTryCount < maxTryCount ) {
                    currentTryCount++
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Loading("loading message"),
                            currentTryCount = currentTryCount
                        )
                    }
                    throw BleReTryableError(throwable.message ?: "")
                } else {
                    myStateFlow.update {
                        it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                            resource = Resource.Error("error message"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .retry {
                delay(2500)
                it is BleReTryableError
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

#### Job4, Job5 ....

Or is it enough  to make a function like the one below?

```
private fun myRun(flow: Flow<Resource<MyType>>) {

}
```

Also extension method is ok for me

Comment: Unclear what you're asking,. You're already collecting it by using `onEach` and `launchIn`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Consider that it's more of the same functions as job1 and all functions are almost the same structure(just useCases1 function different). I want to get rid of dublicate code. i want to write a common function which all job functions use.

Comment: i also edited my question. i hope i clarified situation more better

Comment: If the only thing that varies is the usecase, extract that as a parameter: `job1Job = doTheThing(useCase1)`, `job2Job = doTheThing(useCase2)`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension function like this:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.process(): Job {
    return onEach { resource->
        myStateFlow.update {
            it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                resource = resource,
            )
        }
    }
    .catch {throwable->
        var currentTryCount =
        var maxTryCount =
            if ( throwable is BleReTryableError && currentTryCount < maxTryCount ) {
                currentTryCount++
                myStateFlow.update {
                    it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                        resource = Resource.Loading("loading message"),
                        currentTryCount = currentTryCount
                    )
                }
                throw BleReTryableError(throwable.message ?: "")
            } else {
                myStateFlow.update {
                    it.copy(isConsumed = false,
                        resource = Resource.Error("error message"))
                }
            }
    }
    .retry {
        delay(2500)
        it is BleReTryableError
    }
    .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

And use it like this

```
private var job1Job: Job? = null
private fun job1(param: Param) {
    job1Job?.cancel()
    job1Job = useCases1(param).process()
}
```

for every job you have.

Comment: process function not returing the job can you also update the answer.  I did something on my own, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: also you maybe need to write the function <T: Resource<MyType>> Flow<T>.process() like this.

Comment: @EyeOfTiger now it returns the job